# classOf T instead of T$ for Java library that does reflection

Tags: java, scala, reflection

I'm using Scala with a Java library that expects to be passed a class with a `public static void main(java.lang.String[])` so it can run call it via reflection for integration tests.

```scala
object RestServer {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = { /* run the server */ }
}
```

Due to the behavior described in [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34391003/3198973), this gets compiled to two classes.

```java
public final class com.example.RestServer$ {
  public static final com.example.RestServer$ MODULE$;
  public static {};
  public void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
```

and

```java
public final class com.example.RestServer {
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
```

When I pass the class to the library

```scala
@IntegrationTest(main = classOf[RestServer.type])
class MyTests extends RapidoidIntegrationTest { }
```

I'm actually passing the `object` singleton instance (`RestServer$`), not the `RestServer` class that has the `static void main()` method.

This wouldn't be a problem, except the library verifies that the method it is calling is both `public` and `static` before calling it?

How can I get the `RestServer` class instead?

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok `classOf[RestServer]` doesn't compile. `not found: type RestServer`

Comment: Is it an option that you define an empty companion class `RestServer`? Otherwise I think you are stuck.

Comment: @Jasper-M that's an option, yes, but I don't understand how that helps. I'm more of a CLR than a JVM guy.

Comment: Then you can use `classOf[RestServer]`, because then the class `RestServer` "exists" to Scala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have control over the `RestServer` source file you can add an empty companion class.

```
object RestServer {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = { /* run the server */ }
}

class RestServer
```

That way Scala will recognize that a class `RestServer` exists, so `classOf[RestServer]` will compile and give you the class that contains the static method.